# WPF Commanding problem

Tags: wpf, routed-commands

Why commanded control is always disabled however command can be executed? Command also runs with `Alt + F4`

```
public static class CommandLibrary {
    static CommandLibrary() {
        ShutDownCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Exit", "Exit", typeof(CommandLibrary), new InputGestureCollection {new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt)});
    }

    public static RoutedUICommand ShutDownCommand { get; private set; }

    public static void BindCommands(Window hostWindow) {
        if (hostWindow == null)
            return;

        hostWindow.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ShutDownCommand, OnShutDownCommandExecuted, OnShutDownCommandCanExecute));
    }

    private static void OnShutDownCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("ShutDown Excuted!");
    }

    private static void OnShutDownCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
}

<MenuItem Command="local:CommandLibrary.ShutDownCommand" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this happens because there's no CommandBinding for the command in the scope of the control which has the Command set on it. If you set a breakpoint in the CanExecute handler does it get hit for the MenuItem?